# How to fix "undefined method `user' (ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, collections, associations

I have a user, question and answer model, that I'm aiming to have work like Stack Overflow. I am having issues allowing users to edit or delete only their answers on questions. 
I am using a Helper, which shows a link to edit next to the question:

```
module AnswersHelper
  def own_answers_partial_path
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    if @question.answers.user == current_user
      'answers/own_answer'
    else
      'answers/other_answer'
    end
  end
end
```

However this  results in a undefined method error:

```
'user' for #<Answer::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00000000133d54d8>
```

I understand that `@question.answers.user` is an array, so `@question.answers.user == current_user` will not work.

I tried using:

```
.collect{ |answer| answer.user }
.map{ |answer| answer.user }
.each{ |answer| answer.user }
```

on the array. However they did not work and I don't see how I can use a loop in this case (which I use in the views to get the information).

Is there a way to fix it using this method? Or, do I need to take another approach to allowing users to edit their own answers?

**Answer Controller**

```rb
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_answer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @answers = @question.answers.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @answer = @question.answer.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @answer = @question.answers.build(answer_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @answer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @answer.question, notice: 'Answer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @answer.question }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @answer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @answer.update(answer_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @answer.question, notice: 'Answer was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @answer.question }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @answer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @answer = current_user.answers.find(params[:id])
    @answer.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to answers_url, notice: 'Answer was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_answer
      @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def answer_params
      params.require(:answer).permit(:body).merge(user: current_user, question: @question)
    end

end
```

**Main question and answer view**

```
<%= @question.title %>
Asked by <%= link_to @question.user.email, @question.user %></br>
<%= @question.body %>
</br>
<%= @question.answers.count %> Answers
<%= render @question.answers.order(created_at: :desc) %>
```

**Which links to the answer view**

```
<%= answer.body %></br>
<%= link_to answer.user.first_name, answer.user %> answered <%= time_ago_in_words(answer.created_at) %> ago.
</br>
<%= render own_answers_partial_path %>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve calling `if @question.answers.user == current_user`? According to the method name, I guess you only want to load questions which the `current_user` has answered – is that correct? How do you use that method later on?

Comment: Basically I want to say:

If the answer posted on a question is from current_user, then render a partial.

Comment: If _the_ answer? `answers` is an array. Do you mean if any of the answers is from the `current_user`? Or all answers? What should happen if one answer is from the `current_user` but another answer is not?

Comment: Sorry, if _any_ of the answers are from the `current_user`, show an extra link that allows them to edit or delete their answer. If an answer is not from the `current_user`, do not show a link next to the answer

Comment: Did you consider just having a simple `if answer.user == current_user` block in your view?

Comment: Yes I tried that already, but for some reason `answer.user` is empty. When I check  `answer.user.nil?` it returns true

Comment: Did you check in your database if there are actually users associated with those answers?

Comment: Yes, there is a user associated, and I validate the user in the model as well. I can access `user.answers` in my User view if I use a loop. Similarly, I can access `answer.user` in the Answer view or if I use a loop in other views. But a loop isn't suited to this problem -- or at least I dont know how to effectively use it in this situation

Comment: Can you please post your view?

Comment: I have updated the main post with the Answer controller and the two relevant views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `<%= render own_answers_partial_path %>` in the answer view (that doesn't work because you do not pass local variables to the view) and the additional helper I would just add a simple conditional like this to the answer view

```
<% if answer.user == current_user %>
  <%= link_to 'edit', edit_answer_path(answer) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That solved it! I had been going crazy all day checking my routes, associations, models, controllers and views trying to figure out where the issue was.

Always frustrating when the solution is so simple and elegant and was staring me right in my face

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an expert, but I think you would want to prevent users from editing other user's answers through your controller as well. In the current solution, a malicious user might browse to `/answers/ID`  and bypass your hidden edit link.

// Edit:
For example, in your `AnswersController` include on top:

```
before_action :answer_owner, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Then include at the bottom of your controller, as a private function:

```
    def answer_owner
     unless @answer.user_id == current_user.id
      flash[:notice] = 'Access denied since you are not the owner of this Answer'
      redirect_to answers_path
     end
    end
```

Comment: Im not sure what you mean here. Do you mean I should put a conditional statement in the edit action in the controller?

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean, thats a good tip. Thanks! I'll implement this approach in other areas of my code as well